# Loop Ajax Data in Rails Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a sort function that triggers when I re-order list items.

```js
var articleIds = [];
document.querySelectorAll('.article').forEach(item =>
  articleIds.push(item.dataset.id)
);

Rails.ajax({
  url: '/u',
  type: 'patch',
  data: articleIds
});
```

The articles start as `[ "52", "29", "30", "51" ]`. After the sort `console.log(articleIds)` shows them as `[ "51", "52", "29", "30" ]`. So far, so good.

Trying to see what data I'm getting in the Rails server logs, I've tried:

```rb
params[:id].map.with_index do |id, position|
  puts "position: #{position}, id: #{id}"
end
```

It returns: `NoMethodError (undefined method 'map' for nil:NilClass):`

Thinking this was returning some type of JSON object, I tried:

```rb
articles = JSON.parse(params[:id])
articles.map.with_index do |id, position|
  puts "position: #{position}, id: #{id}"
end
```

This returns the same: `NoMethodError (undefined method 'map' for nil:NilClass):`

If I use `each_with_index` instead of `map` I get `TypeError (no implicit conversion of nil into String):`

How do I loop this Ajax data in a Rails controller?

**Answer:**

I used the `Rails.ajax` call in the accepted answer. This created a string so I had to add `.split(',')` to the block in the controler:

```rb
params[:id].split(',').map.with_index do |id, position|
  puts "position: #{position}, id: #{id}"
position)
end
```

Comment: That says you don't have a parameter named :id.

Comment: Look at the rails log and see what is being passed through the params.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a look at your server logs than you would see that there is no parameter with the name `id`. So you are trying to call map on a nil object.

You could change your ajax request to:

```js
Rails.ajax({
  url: '/u',
  type: 'patch',
  data: `id=${articleIds}`
});
```

This will send a parameter with name id and the value would be the array, so now you can loop through it.